# How do I pass a JSON array into the URL?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

### JavaScript/JQuery

```
var arr=[];

$('.element').each(function(i)
{
    arr.push({"id":i,"value":$(this).attr('data-value')});
});

$.get('/json.php?arr='+arr,function(result)
{
    alert(result);
});
```

### PHP

```
<?php

$j = json_decode($_GET['arr'], true);

foreach($j as $k => $v)
{
    echo $v['id'].':'.$v['value'].'<br />';
}

?>
```

### Problem

But the problem is that the URL looks like `/json.php?arr=[object Object],[object Object]` instead of `/json.php?arr=[{"id":1,"value":"value 1"},{"id":2,"value":"value 2"}]`. Do I need to convert the object to a string? But I don't want to use another library other than JQuery. Is this possible? :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try JSON.stringify

```
$.get('/json.php?arr='+JSON.stringify(arr),function(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't tied to the idea of passing if via JSON, you can provide it in the data part of the jQuery request:

```
$.get( url, data, callback );
```

And then retrieve it later:

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){
   //....
}
```